# Xcode simulator error when accessing files from iCloud --"Could not communicate with a helper function" iOS 13.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter, icloud

I am not able to access files from iCloud using the  simulator.

I have logged in successfully to iCloud and able see the file listing. However, I get the error below  when I select any of the files. This is only happening on the simulator.

Mac version: Mojave 10.14.6
Xcode: Version 11.1 (11A1027)
IOS-13.1

-- Update --

This seems to be happening only iOS 13.1.. I upload simulator 12.4 and it works ok...

[image]
[image]

Comment: We can't help you if you don't share some code.

Comment: There is no code to share.. I am just launching the simulator and select file from the file folder..

Comment: Same here. Present the browser, try to download a video by tapping on it, and it stops showing that message. No idea.

Comment: Are you found a workaround?